# How to change the position within the array

Tags: java

I have one class which is called `people` where I keep track of 50 people, their rank, name, age and order. Then I have a second class called `rearrange` where I have to change the position of the `int order`. So it will change up the order, like order 1 which is in position 0, will be moved to position 48th. I need to do the whole thing without using any loop.

```
class people {
     int order[] = new int[50];
     for(int j=0; j<order.length; j++) {
        order[j] = "order" + j;
        System.out.print(order);
  }
}
class rearrange {
    // In here i need to change the position of the int order, and need to do this without using any loop.
}
```

Comment: Would the rearrange swap all of the elements or only two at a time?

Comment: How would you want to rearrange the array? Sort it? Or just move elements in arbitary positions to arbitary positions?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't rearrange be a method of the people class? Classes are usually created for Nouns, Verbs are usually functions or methods of a class. And wouldn't it be better to have a class "Person" and make an array of 50 of them, and simply change their index to change their order?

Consider something like this:

```
public class Person //create Person class with the attributes you listed
{
    private int rank;
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Person(int rank, int age, String name) //constructor
    {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    Person[] people = new Person[50]; //array of Persons, containing 50 elements

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < people.length(); i++)
        {
            people[i] = new Person(something, something, something); //give all the people some values, you'll have to decide what values you are giving them
        }

        //do something with the rearrange function here
    }

    public static void rearrange(int target, int destination) //this is just a "swap" function 
    {
        Person temp = people[destination];

        people[destination] = people[target];
        people[target] = temp;
    }
}
```